# Thread Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have 2 threads. One thread prints odd numbers and the second thread prints even numbers. Now, I have to execute the threads alternatively so that i can  output 1,2,3,4,5,6,.....

I have written a program for this and this is resulting in a deadlock. Can someone explain what is the problem with the code and how to rectify it?

```
class BooleanObject {
boolean flag;
BooleanObject(boolean flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}
}
class EvenThread extends Thread {
Object lock;
BooleanObject flagObj;
EvenThread(Object o, BooleanObject flag) {
    lock = o;
    this.flagObj = flag;
}
public void run() {
    for (int i=2;i<100;i+=2) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (flagObj.flag == false) {
                flagObj.flag = true;
                lock.notify();
            }
            else {
                try {
                    while (flagObj.flag == true) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
}

class OddThread extends Thread {
Object lock;
BooleanObject flagObj;
OddThread(Object o, BooleanObject flag) {
    lock = o;
    this.flagObj = flag;
}
public void run() {
    for (int i=1;i<100;i+=2) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (flagObj.flag == true) {
                flagObj.flag = false;
                lock.notify();
            }

            else {
                try {
                    while(flagObj.flag == false) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
}

public class EvenOddThreads {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj = new Object();
    BooleanObject flagObj = new BooleanObject(true);
    EvenThread et = new EvenThread(obj,flagObj);
    OddThread ot = new OddThread(obj,flagObj);

    et.setName("even thread");
    ot.setName("odd thread");

    et.start();
    ot.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Its not homework. I am trying to understand multi-threading and the best way is to solve some problems (in my opinion)

Comment: The bug would be more obvious if you marked fields final.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with auto-boxing. When you change `flag` from true to false or vice versa, you are actually getting an entirely new `Boolean` object. That is, this line:

```
flag = false;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
flag = new Boolean(false);
```

Once that happens your two threads are then referring to two different `Boolean` objects, so their flags end up un-synchronized and neither thread is able to signal the other to wake up. When `OddThread` changes the flag `EvenThread` still has the old flag object so it doesn't see the new value.

Because a `Boolean` object is immutable you'll need to change your flag to use some other mutable object which can change values in place without creating new objects. That, or have both classes refer to a common (perhaps global) variable.

As @erickson suggests you could use `AtomicBoolean` which is mutable. Another kludgy way to do it would be to change `flag` to:

```
boolean[] flag = new boolean[1];
```

And then use `flag[0]` every where. Both threads would then be able to change `flag[0]` while always referencing the same `boolean[]` array object. You wouldn't have the auto-boxing problem.

...

Also, it is a good idea to wrap any call to `wait()` in a loop. A `wait()` can be subject to spurious wakeups where the call returns even though nobody has actually called `notify()`. To workaround that you should always check your guarding condition after waking up to make sure the wakeup isn't spurious.

```
while (flag == true) {
    lock.wait();
}
```

---

### Update

> I have made the changes based on your suggestions above; but i am not getting the expected output. I will paste the modified code above. Here is the output i am getting 1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9 10 11 13 12 15 17 14....

When you end up waiting, once you are woken up you don't toggle `flag` and notify the other thread. I advise reorganizing your code a bit so it looks like "wait; print; notify". Something like:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    while (flagObj.flag == false) {
        lock.wait();
    }

    System.out.println(i);

    flagObj.flag = false;
    lock.notify();
}
```

Comment: Alternately you can use Boolean.valueOf() to get the flyweight version. This is better than using the constructor.

Comment: This has nothing to do with autoboxing. It's a scope problem. The same thing would happen if you replaced all `Boolean` types with `boolean` (eliminating autoboxing).

Comment: You're right. Auto-boxing isn't the problem, but it masks the problem by making it superficially look like you're modifying a single `Boolean` object. `flag = new Boolean(true); flag = false;` can be confused for a hypothetical `flag = new Boolean(true); flag.set(false);` which _would_ work, if `Boolean` were mutable.

Comment: Thank You very much. I have made the changes based on your suggestions above; but i am not getting the expected output. I will paste the modified code above. 
Here is the output i am getting 
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9 10 11 13 12 15 17 14....

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't autoboxing. The same thing would happen even if `boolean` primitives were used throughout.

It's a scope problem. Each thread instance has its own `flag` member, and they are completely distinct. When you assign a new value in one thread, the other thread cannot see it.

To make this work as intended, make a *mutable* `boolean` wrapper (an `AtomicBoolean` would do the job, although you wouldn't be making use of its concurrency properties in this application), and pass that wrapper to each thread. Each thread would mutate that single object, rather than assigning a new object to its own variable.

Comment: @erickson Now, i dont get into a deadlock  but i do not get the desired output. I get something like
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9 10 11 13 12 15 17 14.... 
Can you see any problem with the new code?

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two problems here.

1) The first one is this

```
if (flag == true) {
    flag = false;
    lock.notify();
}
```

You pass the flag reference to the constructor, but then you change each thread's local `flag`, which won't affect the other thread's value.

Try something like

```
class Monitor
{
    public static volatile boolean flag;
}
```

And then use `Monitor.flag` in each thread.

2) The second problem (once the 1st one is fixed), is that each thread needs to have this

```
synchronized(lock)
{
    lock.notify();
}
```

at the end after the loop because otherwise one thread will wait() but the other thread is already done.